# What is the lifetime of an ejb client java ee 7

Tags: java-ee-7

Every time I read the word client being used with ejb, I don't understand what they consider a client.

For ejb, what is the lifetime of a client? Does it vary by how the bean refernce is acquired such as jndi or injection.

Is it aligned to an http session, if so how does this relate to jndi?

When does a clients conversation begin and end with an ejb depending on how the reference is acquired?

Does it vary based on whether it is invoked from a java ee 7 container vs. se?

**Edit**: I guess I should be more specific. Stateful session beans maintain state, but in what context and for what extent is that state maintained. If I obtain a reference for example, is the state maintained between calls only made by that reference?

Also how does the concept of session and what is consider a unique client in all types of ejbs?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client of a session bean is any object that obtains a reference to the session bean (via injection or via JNDI lookup). The clients life time doesn't depend on referenced session bean. The client has its own, somehow managed lifecycle and the session bean has its own, independed lifecycle. The lifecycle of session bean depends on its type. There are 3 types of session beans:

`@Singleton` beans lifecycle is very straightforward , only one bean is instantiated in the entire life of an app.

`@Stateful` bean lives as long as its client lives, so its lifetime my vary. Well, it is not technically true because of the passivation mechanism but from a developer perspective you can assume that's true.

An application server creates a pool of `@Stateless` beans at the deployment time. Created instances are distributed across many clients and reused many times by different clients. The important thing here is that ONLY ONE client may use a bean instance at time.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give you my opinion about this which comes from working with EJB (even if not so deep), and i would like to have constructive feedbacks from other users. 
Session comes in 2 flavours: the ejb session and the "others"(client) session.
A client is meant as any entity which is looking up and using the remote interface that you provide, maybe also a local interface and in this case the client and the ejb are running inside the same JVM.

the ejb session is meant as the session managed by the EJB container.
Is not a matter whether is invoked, the session begins when your statefull ejb is looked up and thus created, of course this happens at server side. The ejb has specific way to annotate the duration of the session. After this session is expired you can no more reach such instance of the EJB, thus client side you have no more a reference to something in the server.

On the other side the client has its own session, which is independent from the EJB session, unless you want the two to be related. Let's say that your EJB is managing the login of your client, on firing the ejb time out, your client will no more be logged. But this does not mean that your client session is timed out, maybe it has a longer session.

Think about having a 2 tier architecture with presentation layer and logic layer. Presentation via jsf, which have their own session concept, and logic via EJB on a different server which have their own session managment.

You want the two session to be related each other but they are not the same. You can manage to expire the http/Servlete session upon the ejb time-out, but they are in two different context and related to two different things.